# How to I find F2FS compression ratio

Tags: arch-linux, f2fs

I have `f2fs` partition formatted with `-O extra_attrs,compression`. I've applied `chattr +c` to `/` before installing Archlinux.

`du` shows 6.4G used and `df` shows 6.5G used. Compression algorithm is set in the `fstab`.

How do I check that files are compressed indeed?

Answer (score 0):

`du --apparent-size` should show the size as seen by programs if they were to count the bytes of the files.

Usually this is smaller than the size on disk because, especially for small files, there is wasted space due to the usual 4k-sized blocks but if your files are indeed compressed it should give a larger number than `df`.